# What do you do when Pharo doesn't respond to cmd+.?

Tags: pharo

Sometimes it doesn't bring up a debugger no matter how hard and fast you press cmd+. -- what can be done in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Then you're out of luck really. There's one slight chance (which I have never tried) that you could use `OSProcess` to intercept `SIGUSR1` and then kill / suspend some processes. That's pretty dangerous though.

My advice: frequently save your image and commit your work often. Then you don't really have to care too much; simply kill the VM and restart.

Out of curiosity: which version of Pharo are you using?